# AppInventor - Getting marker position from Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, app-inventor

I want to get the Marker position afer dragging it. Using AppInventor to get the position from the Java Script via setWebViewString function. The map and the drag of the marker are working fine. But the App on AppInventor is not receiving the position from the WebViewer, the WebViewString has no content.

I guess the problem is in this part of the code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    windowAppInventor.setWebViewString(marker.getPosition());
  });
```

Please, can someone review that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

function initialize()
{
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom:15,
    panControl:false,
    zoomControl:true,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    scaleControl:false,
    streetViewControl:false,
    overviewMapControl:false,
    rotateControl:false,    
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  draggable:true,
  });

marker.setMap(map);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    windowAppInventor.setWebViewString(marker.getPosition());
  });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;margin:-8px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the corrected code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

function initialize()
{
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom:15,
    panControl:false,
    zoomControl:true,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    scaleControl:false,
    streetViewControl:false,
    overviewMapControl:false,
    rotateControl:false,    
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

 var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
   position:myCenter,
   draggable:true,  
   });

 marker.setMap(map);
 
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {    
  window.AppInventor.setWebViewString("Lat: " + marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6) + "  Long: " + marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6));
 });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;margin:-8px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```